# Very basic of javascript

Tags: javascript

There is the following code snippet included in the FOSS web-based application:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    // code follows
    // ...
    
  })();
</script>
```

As you can see, the function definition is surrounded by an extra pair of brackets, also followed by another pair of brackets. There is no jQuery or any other JS framework used in the application. The function is not referenced/called later in the script.

Question: What will these characters `(` (very first character of the JavaScript code and `)();` (the last four characters of the js code) cause? And (more importantly) why?

Comment: its an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: It's a self invoked function http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The question is already answered, see the linked question.

Comment: Thank you guys for immediate & useful help. If `Tushar` and `ritesht93` would write your comment as an answer, I would accept it as the solution. This is what I was searching for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is called a closure. It is a self executing function and it means that you can define as many variables as you need without polluting the window namespace.

Comment: Actually, "closure" !== "self-executing function".